# Styling an SVG element via Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG floor plan, and I trying to add a drop down menu that will let people select a location to have it appear on the map.  I have very little experience with jQuery, but this is what I've been able to put together from code I've found while googling:

```js
$(function() {
$('select').change(function() {
var s = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
if(s == "Left") {
$('#rleft').css('fill', 'green');
}
else if(s == "Middle") {
$('#rmiddle').css('fill', 'orange')
}
else if(s == "Right") {
$('#rright').css('fill', 'red')
}
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="blank">Select a Location</option>
<option value="left">Left</option>
<option value="middle">Middle</option>
<option value="right">Right</option>
</select>

<svg height="170" width="500">
<rect id="rleft" x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" />
<rect id="rmiddle" x="170" y="10" width="150" height="150" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" />
<rect id="rright" x="330" y="10" width="150" height="150" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" />
</svg>
```

As it is now, the drop down will change colors, but I'd like the previous selection to be cleared when a new option is selected.  Only one square should have color at a time.  I have a feeling it is something I'm overlooking.  I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: when one square is colored you need to reset the colors of the other squares back to #FFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the style (e.g. set fill:none) for the other elements when the value changes.

```
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var s = $(this).val();
    $('#rleft').css('fill', s == "left"?'green':'none');
    $('#rmiddle').css('fill', s == "middle"?'orange':'none');
    $('#rright').css('fill', s == "right"?'red':'none');
  })
})
```

Comment: I was able to get both answers working, but I found this one the most efficient in the long run.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When one of the squares is selected you need to reset the color of the other squares to #FFF.

Something like this:

```js
if (s == "Left") {
  $('#rleft').css('fill', 'green');
  // set colors back to white
  $('#rmiddle').css('fill', '#FFF');
  $('#rright').css('fill', '#FFF');
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Seems so simple.  I got it to work no problem.  For my actual SVG map, I have 20 or so locations.  I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this without having to do a bunch of extra effort.

Comment: well, assuming you can get your svg elements in an array you could do something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/nNkv5RNBmO4MzlNfuZWM?p=preview

Comment: If you need a more specific solution you will have to provide more information. Maybe ask a different question specific to that?